# Compute the ratio of the sum of cube of the first 'n' natural numbers to the sum of square of first 'n' natural numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Compute the ratio of the sum of cube of the first 'n' natural numbers to the sum of square of first 'n' natural numbers.

Code:

```py
input_int=[x for x in range (1,input_int+1)]
python=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y **3/sum(input_int) % x +y**2/sum(input_int),input_int)
x=10
```

Solution output:

```
62.96363636363636
```

Expected output:

```
7.857142857142857
```

Comment: Please add some context to your question as well as formatting your code.

Comment: You are only squaring and cubing the `y` .. for starters. Dividing through `sum(input_int)` makes no sense at all for your taks.

Comment: Reads like a university/college/interview programming assignment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce
import ast,sys
input_int = int(sys.stdin.read())

num_list = [x for x in range(1, input_int+1)]
print(reduce(lambda x, y : x + y ** 3, num_list) / reduce(lambda x, y : x + y ** ,num_list))
```

Comment: Please consider adding a description of your code so we know what it does and why.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very hard to understand and does not even run.

Based on your description of the goal, I can suggest a simpler code to achieve it:

```
def calc_ratio(n):
    sum_3 = sum(x**3 for x in range(1, n+1))
    sum_2 = sum(x**2 for x in range(1, n+1))
    return sum_3 / sum_2
```

This would give these results:

```
>>> calc_ratio(10)
7.857142857142857
>>> calc_ratio(100)
75.3731343283582
>>> calc_ratio(1000)
750.3748125937032
>>> calc_ratio(10000)
7500.374981250938
>>> calc_ratio(100000)
75000.37499812501
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
from functools import reduce
import ast,sys
input_int = int(sys.stdin.read())
num_list = [x for x in range(1, input_int+1)]
print(reduce(lambda x, y : x + y ** 3, num_list) / reduce(lambda x, y : x + y **2 ,num_list))
```

Comment: Please format your answer properly before submitting it. Please go through the below guide on how to do formatting in StackOverflow:- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks